# function template specialization for mixed class and int

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I was studying about template specialization but unable to understand mixed class and int.

The following code fails to compile [click to compile](http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/qvnlaO). Can someone suggest the right way here. I wish to specialize for int class. the second template m should be defined as 0 but how to specify that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T,int m>
void fun(T a )
{
cout << "The main template fun(): " << a  << "  " << m << endl;
}

template<>
void fun(int a)
{
    cout << "Specialized Template for int type: " << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
    fun<char,10>('a');
    fun<int,20>(10);
    fun<float,12>(10.14);
}
```

The error is:

```
prog.cpp:11:6: error: template-id 'fun<>' for 'void fun(int)' does not match any template declaration
 void fun(int a)
      ^
```

Comment: You cannot partially specialize function as you want to.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to change order of parameter to let T be deduced, then simply use overload:

```
template <int m, class T>
void fun(T a )
{
    cout << "The main template fun(): " << a  << "  " << m << endl;
}

template <int m>
void fun(int a)
{
    cout << "Template for int type: " << a << endl;
}
```

With usage:

```
fun<10>('a');
fun<20>(10);
fun<12, float>(10.14); // or simply fun<12>(10.14f);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you're trying to do is to specialise the template so that any call of the form

```
fun<int, N>(...);
```

Calls the specialisation?

This would require a partial specialisation of `fun()` for `int`, but the C++ language forbids partially specialising function templates. However, we can partially specialise class templates just fine. So one approach to do what you want would be to implement your `fun()` function using function objects, like so:

```
// General case
template <typename T, int N>
struct do_fun {
     void operator()(T a) {
        cout << "The main template fun(): " << a  << "  " << N << endl;  
     } 
};

// Specialisation for int
template <int N>
struct do_fun<int, N> {
    void operator()(int a) {
        cout << "Specialized Template for int type: " << a << endl;
    }
};
```

You can then supply a wrapper function template that uses the function objects:

```
template <typename T, int N>
void fun(T a) {
    do_fun<T, N>{}(a);
}
```

[Coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3870261e2256a074)